# Bootstrap tr info Class info Doesn't Work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class

When I try to apply the `info` class to a tr tag no row formatting is applied Success, Danger and Warning classes work as expected.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="info"><td>bla<td>bla</tr> //doesn't work, supposed to be blue
    <tr class="warning"><td>bla<td>bla</tr> //does work 
    <tr class="danger"><td>bla<td>bla</tr> //does work 
</table>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables for examples of info class working.

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.*

Comment: Could you add the code that you're using into your question so people could find out what's wrong with it?

Comment: I've edited the question, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: First please note that your HTML markup is invalid, you didn't close the `<td>` tags. However it works well for me: http://jsbin.com/uVuLOgoX/1/edit

Comment: As I said, I work with united theme for bootstrap...

Comment: @HashemQolami Unclosed td elements are allowed; the end tags are optional. It's in the specs.

Comment: @user3185123 Your result png is not loading for me.

Comment: @MrLister You're right. That's valid HTML but invalid XHTML

Comment: In case it does not get reopened, the Info class was not added to the LESS until December 2013: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/fe58357df182b52f5905f432a3b2629c717656f1.  So if you downloaded your copy of Bootstrap before then, but were using the online documentation, you would encounter this issue.  The demo provided by @HashemQolami used the online css files, so of course it worked without issue.